# Is it possible to share network PC to PC?

Tags: linux, networking

Is it possible to somehow share a WiFi connection from PC to another PC on Linux?

I have a laptop which can connect to WiFi but my other PC cannot because it doesn’t have a WiFi card. I need to SSH into the PC but can’t do so because it doesn’t have WiFi card. Ethernet cable from router is also not an option because my router is in the other room.

Both devices run Arch Linux.

I’ll be thankful for any help that you could provide.

Comment: If both PC's also have a network card and cable in between, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect the two computers with an Ethernet cable and enable network sharing on the host machine. In Windows this can be done through the Sharing tab in the properties window of your Ethernet cable in the "Network Connections" Control Panel. In Linux it depends on your distro and desktop environment.

Comment: I tried it today and it didn't work. I use Arch Linux with BSPWM.